# On which amino-acids residue is the SDS acting on?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, lab-techniques, amino-acids, sds-page

I would like to know exactly what is the mechanisme of the SDS, and I would like to know on which amino-acids residue the SDS is acting on.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your talking about Sodium Dodecyl Sulfate(a detergent) it has a two main functions:

**(1)** It disrupts all non-covalents bonds in proteins i.e hydrogen bonds from the main chain, or hydrogen bonds between residues which are dependent on protein shape.

**(2)** It coats the proteins with a negative charge which is useful for laboratory techniques such as gel electrophoresis.

Your question states "*what amino acid residues does it act on?*". You can be safe to assume that the SDS will coat the entire protein. About 0.1% SDS solution is enough to sature the polypetide chains of protein molcules with about one SDS molecule per two amino acid residues.